# How do I turn off jQuery for server side control?

Tags: jquery, telerik

I am facing an issue with a jQuery method. I am using ASP .NET 2013 for code development using Telerik Controls.

After adding a server side Telerik TEXTBOX for entering comments on the page, jQuery is making the server side textbox not editable and it incorrectly shows the error message "wrong barcode". The current page has a DATAGRID view and one column is item template to ASP:BUTTON, which will show up a text box where I can enter the comments, on click.

I am attaching the jQuery method template and controls as attachmnts.

[image: Code template]

Your help is much appreciated. I can replace this textbox with an ASP text box as well. Currently I am using telerik text box.
Need your help to turn off `$(document).ready()` for RdTxtLeadComments text box.

Comment: They are probably using a validation on all text boxes, or something similar. You have to open the .js file that is actually calling the $(document).ready() function. You cannot turn it off another way.

Comment: Proper casing, grammar edits. Remove personal history.